# Export User Statistics from ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

Is there any way to export usage statistics to csv from an ArcGIS Online institutional account?  I would specifically like to be able to identify the number of times logging in or total time logged in as well as number and type of items created.

Comment: I believe the free version of the GeoJOBE tools allows for this.

Answer (score 1):

Go to > My Organization > View Status > Credits and note the Download icon towards the right-hand side:
[image]

Comment: PS I need to buy more credits......